# Netbeans cannot find java

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk, oracle, netbeans

I uninstalled Openjdk 7 and installed Oracle Java from [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html). But after the installation Netbeans won't start. I have tried all the methods posted online about editing the `netbeans.conf` file and entering the path:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

or

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac
```

I even entered the path from terminal typing `./netbeans --jdkhome=""`.

Any help is greatly aprreciated.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make  then `umake ide netbeans`

Answer (score 1):

The option for setting the jdkhome is not `--jdkhome=""`. There should be a space rather than an equals sign between --jdkhome and the path.

eg.

```
netbeans  --jdkhome "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/"
```

If you get it wrong, such as:

```
netbeans  --jdkhome "/wrong/"
```

the error message you can see when starting on the terminal should be:

```
Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch.
```

If you are getting no error message or a different error message, the problem may not be with setting the JDK directory.

I would recommend you not try to run the Netbeans version which is in the Ubuntu repositories (7.0.1 for Ubuntu 14.04)  and instead get 8.0.2 from netbeans.org or the version bundled with the JDK on Oracle's website.

When I run Netbeans 7.0.1 with JDK 1.8 it shows the splash and crashes.

Comment: Well that didn't work so un-installation and re-installation resulted in a prompt to select java at the beginning of the installation, thanks though!